# Why bootstrap truncates text in button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For unknown reason I get text in my button truncated. My html is:

```
<input class="btn btn-default" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."/>
```

And it's how it looks:
[image]

I can set width in percents or in pixels, and it works fine, but I want to button fit the text length only and avoid width hardcoding, is possible.

I didn't override any bootstrap css, as you can see, I do not use custom classes/ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."/>`

You were missing the `type="submit"`, meaning it's defaulted to a text input.

Comment: I definitly should take a break... Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the type attribute of your `button` to make your input as a button.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."/>
```